# Getting selenium python to run previous line of code after catching an exception

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrape this **[Website](https://www.compareandrecycle.co.uk/mobile-phones/apple-iphone-11)**. It has two dropdown lists that I need to navigate as shown in the image below:

[image]

I solved an issue where I get a `StaleElementReferenceException` on each of the dropdowns since I need to execute a click before the elements come into view. However, after catching the exception, I need the webdriver to go back to the previous line of code to click it into view again. Is there another argument I call, rather than the `pass` argument, that could make that happen?

The `pass` argument does not work, and since I am a little new to web scraping, am having a challenge seeing what else to do.

Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, ElementNotInteractableException, StaleElementReferenceException
from time import sleep

options1 = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options1.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options1)

link = "https://www.compareandrecycle.co.uk/mobile-phones/apple-iphone-11"

driver.get(link)
sleep(5)
cookie_button = driver.find_element("xpath", "//span[@class='cookie_acceptButton__gs5MX']").click()
for x in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='storage-selectors']/span"))):
            size = x.text
            print(size)
            try:
                variants = x.click()
            except ElementNotInteractableException:
                pass
            
            network_options = driver.find_element("xpath", "//div[@class='network-options']//span[@class='selectboxit selectboxit-enabled selectboxit-btn']")
            network_options.click()
            sleep(3)
            for elem in driver.find_elements("xpath", "//div[@class='network-options']//div[@class='selectboxit-options selectboxit-list']/li"):
                try:
                    elem.click()
                except StaleElementReferenceException:
                    pass
                network = driver.find_element("xpath", "//div[@class='network-options']//span[@class='selectboxit selectboxit-enabled selectboxit-btn']/span[@class='selectboxit-text']").text
                print(network)
                
                sleep(3)
                condition_options = driver.find_element("xpath","//div[@class='condition-options']//span[@class='selectboxit selectboxit-enabled selectboxit-btn']")
                condition_options.click()
                sleep(3)
                for cons in driver.find_elements("xpath", "//div[@class='condition-options']//div[@class='selectboxit-options selectboxit-list']/li"):
                    try:
                        cons.click()
                    except StaleElementReferenceException: 
                        pass
                    condition = driver.find_element("xpath", "//div[@class='condition-options']//span[@class='selectboxit selectboxit-enabled selectboxit-btn']/span[@class='selectboxit-text']").text
                    print(condition)
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? the XPath - "//div[@class='storage-selectors']/span" does not have any match in that website.

Comment: @AbiSaran thanks for noting that. I have a list of links. I seem to have used the wrong one which doesn't have that feature. I have edited the question with the right link. Let me know what you think.

Comment: Did you want a simple for for loop for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
driver.get('https://www.compareandrecycle.co.uk/mobile-phones/apple-iphone-11')

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@class,'cookie_accept')]"))).click()
j=0
while True:
    try:
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.network-options > div > div > span"))).click()
        networks=wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.selectboxit-options.selectboxit-list>li")))
        networks[j].click()
        i=0
        while True:
            try:
                wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.condition-options > div > div > span"))).click()
                conditions=wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.selectboxit-options.selectboxit-list>li")))
                conditions[i].click()
                i+=1
            except:
                break
        j+=1
    except:
        break
```

You could either open it up and get the length and then loop or just loop until your erroring out and click on all the options.

Just add this to the top of the loop for all the sizes as well convert to Webdriver waits.

```
sizes = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//span[contains(@class,'filter-box')]") 
for i in range(len(sizes)): 
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,f"(//span[contains(@class,'filter-box')] )[{i}]").click()
```

Comment: Thanks @Arundeep. The loop you created really helped. I am looking to loop and click while grabbing the text for each dropdown item.

Comment: Again, each of the dropdowns has size equivalents. So I wanted to click on each size and then loop through the drop-downs, and then move to the next size. Any ideas how to adjust the code to do that?

Comment: Just add another for loop on the top so it's O(n^3). You don't need to open anything up.

Comment: Thanks so much. This works very fine with just a little tweak. You've been a great help @Arundeep

Comment: Quick question again @Arundeep. Am trying to write exceptions for other pages that do not have these features that I have to loop through like [this](https://www.compareandrecycle.co.uk/mobile-phones/razer-phone-2) and [this](https://www.compareandrecycle.co.uk/mobile-phones/razer-razer-phone). Whenever I try adding exceptions, the loop gets messed up. Any ideas?